# Extra white space below table view using search bar Swift Xcode

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, tableview, uisearchbar

I have a `UITableView`, When i'm scrolling down to the bottom there is extra white space almost in a size of a full cell at the bottom,
in that `ViewController` i have a search bar iv'e added this way:

On `ViewDidLoad`:

```
searchController.searchResultsUpdater = self
searchController.hidesNavigationBarDuringPresentation = false
searchController.dimsBackgroundDuringPresentation = false
searchController.searchBar.sizeToFit()
searchController.searchBar.setValue("ביטול", forKey:"_cancelButtonText")
searchController.searchBar.placeholder = "חפש כאן..."
let searchTextField = searchController.searchBar.value(forKey: "_searchField") as! UITextField
searchTextField.textAlignment = NSTextAlignment.right

if #available(iOS 9.0, *) {
    searchController.searchBar.semanticContentAttribute = .forceRightToLeft
}
let attributes = [NSAttributedStringKey.foregroundColor : UIColor.white]
if #available(iOS 9.0, *) {
    UIBarButtonItem.appearance(whenContainedInInstancesOf: [UISearchBar.self]).setTitleTextAttributes(attributes, for: .normal)
}
tableOrder.tableHeaderView = searchController.searchBar
```

Iv'e found out that if i'm taking off the search bar code, The table view appearance is all good and when i'm bringing back the code that extra white space is coming back.

- I've try to change the content insets value to none with no success.
- Iv'e try to tic off the adjust scroll view insets from the `ViewController`
- Iv'e checked the constraints to make sure they all good.

How can i make that white space to disappear ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try 2 ways to fix this problem:
1st:

```
tableView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 0, -29, 0);
```

2nd:

```
tableView.tableFooterView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 0, height: CGFloat.leastNonzeroMagnitude))
```

Or just:

```
tableView.tableFooterView = UIView()
```

Answer (score 0):

Check the following for your `UIViewController` in **storyboard** :
**Extend Edges**
1. *Under Opaque Bars*
2. *Under Bottom Bars*

[image]

Comment: Hello and thank you for you'r answer, i had the : under Bottom Bars missing and iv'e added it up, but still no success

Comment: I have edited my answer, Sorry pressed enter by mistake